# Stripe + Laravel Cashier troubles (No Such Token)

Tags: php, laravel

I've read the other questions related to the "No Such Token" Error but they didn't seem to help me much.

```
Route::post('charge', function(){
    $creditCardToken = Input::get('stripeToken');
    Auth::user()->newSubscription('pro', 'pro')->create($creditCardToken);
});
```

This is what I have. My error is:
No such token: tok_17NcVXG5nWv8W80Jrdpl7Iz3; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.

Since it says that a similar object exists in test mode, I tried to put the test API key into my services and my .env file but when I do that, I ironically get an error that is identical.. only that this time it says that "a similar object exists in live mode"

Does anyone know what's going on and how I can solve this?